# Always run node with the --harmony flag

Tags: windows, node.js

I always want to run Node.JS with the `--harmony` flag. Is there a way to easily have this flag turned on by default?

(Note: I'm running on Windows, so I only have access to Cygwin or Mingw as shells.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are talking about running interactively, you can use a bash `alias`. Put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias node="node --harmony"
```

---

(For the below: note that when I say "executable", I don't just mean binaries or ".exe files". "Executables" include anything that can be executed without explicitly invoking an interpreter, which includes scripts with a shebang.)

If you want to run an executable, e.g. within another script, you can create a shell script that launches the target with the extra flag:

Create a `nodeHarmony` and put it in your search path, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`:

```
#!/bin/sh

node --harmony "$@"
```

Then `chmod a+x` it.

Then execute `nodeHarmony` whenever you want that flag appended. If you want to replace the `node` executable, you could probably rename `node` to something else (e.g. `node_original`), name the script `node`, and use `node_original` within the script.

You could also create the equivalent Windows batch script, which would work outside Cygwin/MinGW:

```
@echo off

node --harmony %*
```

This would behave similarly, but may exhibit odd effects with some argument combinations, because the list would get parsed twice - once when executing the batch script, and once within the script when executing `node`. Some workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5338799/1030702).

Answer (score 4):

If you are ready to recompile node.js, the article
[How to obtain harmony in your node.js](http://www.goatslacker.com/post/16000243520/how-to-obtain-harmony-in-your-node-js) says :

> Once you’ve got the source code, open up
>   `deps/v8/src/flag-definitions.h` and look for Line 115.  Change the
>   flag from false to true :
>
> ```
> DEFINE_bool(harmony, true, "enable all harmony features")
> ```
>
> Then compile Node :
>
> ```
> ./configure && make && make install
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently https://www.npmjs.org/package/setflags can be used to set the flags at runtime, however [I couldn't get it to install](https://github.com/tjfontaine/node-setflags/issues/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit node.js file and:

1. Search for a variable that checks its setting for "--harmony" or "harmony", something like:

   ```
   if (variable_name == 'harmony') ...
   ```
2. Set this variable earlier in code:

   ```
   var this_variable_name = 'harmony';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you config the **package.json** with a **scripts** command?

For example, add to package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --harmony server.js"
  }
```

Then run in cmd (in the project directory):

> npm start